# Wordpress - how to add a button very next to 'Add new category' in post edit view and uncheck all selected categories?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to place a button next to the 'Add new category' button in edit post or new post page.
The purpose of this button will be to uncheck/unselect all the selected categories from that post.
If knows please let me know is it possible ??If yes then how or what specific hook/filter can be used to do it ?

I tried to find the solution but could not found anything that could really help me.
I'm expecting the right direction to make it possible if its possible to do.

Comment: is this a planed feature for your users, or just a one-time thing that you need (remove all categories from all posts)? If the latter, there are better ways to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Its not for users, Its for admin only. Actually the case is when multiple categories are selected, It takes time to uncheck/unselect all the categories one by one. 

So there is need of a button or call to action that can help to uncheck all the selected categories at once...

Comment: Not exactly your use-case, but maybe this will help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-remove-posts-from-category/